# Update record in DB with Composite Primary Key

Tags: jpa, spring-boot, sql-update, composite-primary-key

I have the following mapping table C for table A and B. A & B have one-to-many relation with C table

```
+-----------+----------+--------+---------+
|    A_ID   |  B_ID    | 
+-----------+----------+--------+---------+
|    2      |    4     |  
|    5      |    1     |  
+-----------+----------+--------+---------+
```

Here A_ID & B_ID is composite key for table C, I would like to know If I want to update any record mapping in C, Should I first Delete the old record and add a new one?

But I don't think it's the best way to do this. So could anyone help me to find a better way to update the record?

Note: I'm using Spring boot so hope to find a way to do so by JPA NamedQuery.

Comment: what do you mean by "update any record in C". Table C is created automatically when you define relation between A and B. So you can update anything in A and B. YOu dont explicitly do anything in C

Comment: show us your jpa code that you are trying to use right now. Will make thins clearer

Comment: @pvpkiran I like update mapping between i.e. 2 and 4 to let say 2 and 7. I'm not talking about changes in A or B table, rather in C.

Comment: However, SQL Update query works fine but I want to this programmatically

Comment: if you want to change mapping from 2-->4 to 2-->7. Then you need to get object 2 from table A and then set the B reference of 2 to 7 and then save A. Doing this will change the entries in C automatically

Comment: @pvpkiran I've tried that way not worked, could please make sure about the mapping relation, A & B have one-to-many relation with C table.

Comment: JPA operates around objects, not tables. Use JPA and you need to express what you want with reference to the OBJECTS. If you can't do that then JPA is not for you.